"Certainty" of a random event
Possibly duplicate of
Number of events to achieve a certainty
but I still don't understand, so I still need to ask.
I have a black box. When I open it, there is 1/400 chance of it not being empty. Otherwise it's empty. Basically success or fail event, with chance of success 1/400.
So I make a program that calculates how many times I need to open it to have something inside. Over 10 million iterations the number was always less than 6000.
So probability of success (what I named as "certainty" in the title) grows with amount of attempts. Is there an analytical expression that would describe this?

Yours does not seem to me a duplicate of the linked question...

It is not clear what you mean by "probability of success grows with amount of samples." The law of large numbers says $$\frac{\mbox{total successes in $n$ independent attempts}}{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{400}$$ with probability 1. Basic probability says $P[\mbox{at least one success in $n$ attempts}]=1-\left(\frac{399}{400}\right)^n$

Let's look at a similar problem.  One of the simplest such problems might be counting the number of rolls of a die until we see a $1$.  Let's call this number $X$.
If our die is fair, the probability of seeing a $1$ on the first roll is $1/6$.  If we see a $1$ for the first time on the second roll, it's because we saw some other number on the first roll.  That number appears with probability $5/6$, and the $1$ appears, again, with probability $1/6$; multiplying these two (since the rolls are independent), we get $P(X = 2) = 5/36$.
We can reason similarly for any such value of $X$:  We see our first $1$ on the $n$th roll only if all the first $n - 1$ rolls show numbers between $2$ and $6$.  Therefore, $P(X = n) = (1 - p)^{n-1} p$, where $p = 1/6$ is our probability of success.
From here, you can compute the probability that it takes at most $n$ rolls to see a $1$:  This is simply
$$P(X \le n) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(X = k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (1-p)^{n-1}p.$$
Since increasing $n$ adds more terms to your sum, each of which is positive, the effect is, as you write, that the probability increases.
Let's say you wanted to be $99$ percent "certain" -- there is rarely $100$ percent certainty in these questions -- that you'll roll a $1$ within $n$ attempts.  Since the above finite geometric series can be simplified as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (1-p)^{n-1}p = p\frac{1 - (1 - p)^n}{1 - (1 - p)} = 1 - (1 - p)^n,$$
we can solve for $n$:
\begin{align}
0.99 &= 1 - (5/6)^n \\
0.01 &= (5/6)^n \\
\ln 0.01 &= n \ln(5/6) \\
n &= \frac{\ln 0.01}{\ln (5/6)} \\
&\approx 25.26. 
\end{align}
And so we bump $n$ up to $26$, since rounding down to $25$ would make us only $98$ and change percent sure.  We'll be a bit more than $99$ percent sure if we roll the die $26$ times, but that's okay.
Swapping in $p = 1/400$ for your problem, you can compute similar probabilities.
Your problem, by the way, has a name:  It's a geometric distribution.
